# How to show all Y-Axis Labels in Matplotlib in TimeLine Chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, google-colaboratory

In the below code I plotted a time-line chart but I don't know how can I show all Y-axis values by integer type and standard interval. Does anyone has any idea?

[image]

code link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Fq91PXlylJMKh6oUpysM95gpLwBfUcGx?usp=sharing

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams.update(matplotlib.rcParamsDefault)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,7))
ax.barh(df.year, df.days_start_to_end, left=df.startNum, color=df.color)

xticks = np.arange(0, df.endNum.max()+1, 3)
xticks_labels = pd.date_range(proj_start, end=df.end.max()).strftime("%m/%d ")
xticks_minor = np.arange(0, df.endNum.max()+1, 1)
#ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df.year)))
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
#ax.set_xticks(xticks_minor, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks_labels[::3])

c_dict = { 'Perfect': '#4db249', 'Good':'#539de3',
          'Normal':'#ffbd63', 'Severe': '#ff7361', 'Drastic':'#ff2626'}
legendEl = [Patch(facecolor = c_dict[i], label = i) for i in c_dict]
plt.legend(handles = legendEl)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dates (year) that you have are just numbers and not datetime. If you would like to see all the labels in Y-axis, you can simply convert that column to string while plotting. This will tell matplotlib that these are texts and need to be plotted as categorical data. Below is the updated line... Note that this will plot the years without the decimal. Hope you don't need that.

```
ax.barh(df.year.astype('string'), df.days_start_to_end, left=df.startNum, color=df.color)
```

**Updated plot**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how can I show df['frequency'] label on each timeline bar? I tested different codes but doesn't work for timeline.

Comment: There isn't a short-cut to doing this. Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-the-value-of-each-bar-in-a-bar-chart-using-matplotlib/). You will need to use text annotation and adjust x,y positions based on your bar to display this. Another option is to use plotly, something like [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/text-and-annotation-for-timeline-plots-gantt-plot/54618/2), but this would keep the text inside/outside only... less flexible